# This proposal is 100% ... we're preparing its launch ... why the wait?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, area-51

It's a long old haul getting through Definition and Commitment. When the magic 100% commitment is reached, it's a big moment for those who've contributed.

So why the wait for the site? Seems to me the typical wait is several days. How much "preparing" is required, behind the scenes, for a private beta? Surely you flick a switch?

BTW one of the sites currently in 100% limbo is http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1369/gardening-and-landscaping.

OK, so gardeners are supposed to be a patient lot, but stilll.

Comment: Erm...Which proposal are you referring to specifically?

Comment: a few days is tolerable, but it does seem like gardening & landscaping has been in limbo longer than the usual site

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For a number of reasons, we have somewhat of a schedule throughout the week for launching proposals.  Lately, we've had more proposals to launch than can fit into our schedule for a week, so there have been a couple that get held over until the next week.  Gardening is an example of this.

Something tells me you might be a bit happier in a couple of hours though. (:

Comment: yay! it's there!

Answer (score 11):

At the very least, a temporary logo, favicon, and domain have to be set up. This is a manual process—for example, if Jin, the SE designer, is busy with a new final site design for an existing site, the temp logo and favicon for the proposal site are probably going to be pushed back a little.

Additionally, the software has to be reconfigured for a new site, and the Community Coordinators (Robert Cartaino, Rebecca Chernoff, Dori Smith, Shog9 (aka Josh Heyer)) have to be ready to help the site move along in the first few days before moderators are appointed.

Basically, a lot of the work is already done, but there a few final things that have to be done for each individual site. The wait is typically a few days (recently, due to launching some international sites that may have language issues, they've been slowing down to make sure those don't encounter problems), but it shouldn't be terribly intolerable in any case.

Comment: logo etc can be created a few days before they are needed by looking at "rate of progress"   However I think this issue will go away if the message was beter.